# What's the difference between a Child window and a Descendent window?

Tags: windows, user-interface

I am reading from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this:

> A child window has only one parent
>   window, but a parent can have any
>   number of child windows. Each child
>   window, in turn, can have child
>   windows. In this chain of windows,
>   each child window is called a
>   descendant window of the original
>   parent window. An application uses the
>   IsChild function to discover whether a
>   given window is a child window or a
>   descendant window of a given parent
>   window.

I am still confused about the difference between a Child window and a Descendent window.

I am using Mita.Foundation.dll to manipulate the IE and Desktop UI. It has the following 2 properties, I don't know what's the difference and I got no document for this DLL.

```
UIObject.Children
UIObject.Descendents
```

This concept is critical to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Window A
    Window B
        Window C
```

`B` is both a child and a descendant of `A`.

`C` is not a child of `A` but it is a descendant of `A`.

Or, for an analogy, consider someone who is a grandparent.  His grandchildren are descendants of him but they are not his children.

Comment: I maximize an IE window, an html button is included in the IEwindow.Descendents. But if I minimize the IE windows, the html button is not included, this is not reasonable. Is this how Windows work?

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer?  What HTML button?  When you view the window tree (using, e.g., Spy++), what shows up?

Comment: IE9. the above info happens with Mita.Foundation.dll. I do the similar thing with SHDocVw and mshtml, things are fine.

Comment: the HTML button is just an input button included in a test html file.

Comment: I am not at all familiar with Mita.Foundation.dll, sorry.